# Making a text box only have multiples of 5

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a textbox give a message to the user if they enter the number 1, in it for example.  It should then show a pop up saying that this product is only available in multiples of 5.

Here is my code.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function chk_boxquantity(inField) {
    step3_submit_disable();

    var fVal = inField.value;
    var fBoxQuantity = 5;

    if (mod(fVal, fBoxQuantity) != 5) {
        alert('This product is only available in multiples of '+fBoxQuantity);
        inField.value = Math.ceil(fVal/fBoxQuantity)*fBoxQuantity;
        setTimeout(function() {
            inField.focus();inField.select();gAutoBlur = false;
        }, 10);
    }

    step3_submit_enable();
}
</script>
```

Here is the text field.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event);" 
onblur="chk_boxquantity(this);" name="qty[<?php echo $card['id']; ?>]" 
size="3" />
```

So wherever, the user clicks, it will pop up with the message.  This is not working though, any ideas why not?

Thanks,

Jonah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Code From `mod()` to `% operator` [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/anapoy/1/edit)

**FROM**

```
 if (mod(fVal, fBoxQuantity) != 5)
```

**TO**

```
  if ((fVal % fBoxQuantity) != 0)
```

**Complete Function may look like**

```
function chk_boxquantity(inField)
{
    var fVal = inField.value;
    var fBoxQuantity = 5;

    if ((fVal % fBoxQuantity) !== 0)
    {
     alert('This product is only available in multiples of '+fBoxQuantity); 
      inField.value = Math.ceil(fVal/fBoxQuantity)*fBoxQuantity ;
    }

}
```

**Only required code is shown.**

Comment: I downvoted because it was a code only answer. It is good now, removed downvote :)

Comment: Thank you all.  All your comments have really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
if (mod(fVal, fBoxQuantity) != 5) {
```

to:

```
if ((fVal % fBoxQuantity) != 0) {
```

You can see a description of the modulus operator [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Modulus.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the remainder of the mod operation, if it is larger than zero, it was not divisible by 5

```
// mod
10 % 5 === 0

// div
10 / 5 === 2
```

So, you will need to to change your `!= 5` to `!= 0`